# Append an extension to only certain files in a directory via command line

Tags: bash, command-line, linux-mint

I have my QtWidgets folder with a bunch of header files. The only issue i'm having is a lot of the files don't have a `.cpp` extension. I was wondering if there was a way to loop through the directory and add `.cpp` to all the files that don't have a `.h` extension?

i've started trying with something like this:

```
paul@pauls-computer:~/QtWidgets$ for f in *; do echo '.cpp'
```

But that's just the beginning, and it doesn't even do anything yet. Let alone check for files that are appended with `.h` or not.

So, I've already marked an appropriate answer, but there seems to be some confusion. I have many files, they all have either no extension, or they have a `.h` extension. There are no other extensions.

Comment: So, if you have a file `foo.c`, it should become `foo.c.cpp`, since it does not end in `.h`, right?

Comment: I only have `.h` and files without an extension. So there are no `.c` files. So i'm not worried about `.c` being an issue

Comment: I don't know what files you have in your directory. If you only have .cpp and .h and it is **guaranteed** that you don't have anything else (such as `Makefile` or `foo.bar` or `xy.sh`), you are safe of course.

Comment: That is correct! It was more of an experiment with the QtWidtets folder. If you look in the QtWidgets folder youll see what the contents are. I wanted to see if i could build it from that. That didnt work thoguh. Even tho i was able to append all the  extensions. Vscode complained that the files weren't actually c or c++. Im attempting different ways to build Qt. https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `.cpp` should not be added to any files ending in `.h` or `.cpp`:

```
mkdir /tmp/test.$$
cd /tmp/test.$$
touch a.h b.cpp c d e.cpp

for f in *
do
    [[ "${f}" == *.h || "${f}" == *.cpp ]] && continue
    echo mv "${f}" "${f}.cpp"
done
```

This generates:

```
mv c c.cpp
mv d d.cpp
```

Once OP has confirmed the correct `mv` commands are displayed then remove the `echo` and run the script again to perform the actual `mv`'s.

**NOTES:**

- I highly recommend OP peruse the current files to see if there are any other extensions that should be skipped (in addition to `.h` and `.cpp`) before removing the `echo`
- if OP comes up with a better definition of what files to **NOT** add `.cpp` to (update the question with said details) then we can come back and look at a modification to the proposed code

---

Assuming OP ran a script that accidentally added a `.cpp` to a file that already had a `.cpp` ...

```
mkdir /tmp/test.$$
cd /tmp/test.$$
touch a.h b.cpp c d e.cpp j.cpp.cpp

for f in *.cpp.cpp
do
    g="${f/.cpp/}"
    echo mv "${f}" "${g}"
done
```

This generates:

```
mv j.cpp.cpp j.cpp
```

Again, once the displaed `mv` command(s) is verified as correct then remove the `echo` and run the script again to perform the actual `mv`'s.

Comment: Maybe generalize to skip files which contain a dot (which presumably then already have an extension) and directories.

Comment: yeah, thought about that but **I** tend to create files with dots (not related to extensions) so am hesitant to go that route as a generic solution; OP really needs to come back with a better description of when to apply the `.cpp` extension

Comment: nice this works my friend. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using `file` command allows to detect type without relaying on the extension only.

```
> file Pet 
Pet: C++ source, ASCII text

> file c-source 
c-source: C source, ASCII text
```

Taking advantage of that we could

- `find`: files (not directories), not ending in `.h, .cpp`
- Keep lines matching `C++ source, C source` only
- keep filename only (`cut -d ':' -f1`)
- Add cpp extension to those

  ```
  while read -r cppfile; do 
      mv "$cppfile" "${cppfile}.cpp"
  done < <(find . -type f -not -name '*.h' -not -name '*.cpp' -exec file {} ';' | grep -E 'C(\+\+)? source' | cut -d ':' -f1)
  ```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to traverse subdirectories, try `find`.

```sh
find . -type f \( ! -name '*.cpp' -a ! -name '*.h' \) \
    -exec sh -c 'for f; do echo mv "$f" "$f.cpp"; done' _ {} +
```

You can add more conditions if you like. Take out the `echo` once you are satisfied with the result.  `-type f` selects files (not directories, symlinks, etc) and you might want to restrict to `! -name '*.*'` instead of the long parenthesized expression to skip any file with a dot in its name.

Comment: Bash has problems with exclamation marks if you have `set -H` but it should be harmless here. Still mentioning in case other shells have similar mechanisms. In Bash, try `set +H` if you get `!something: event not found`